# Background Worker not starting when class in instantiated

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a class called **ClientSocketService** which when instantiated creates a background thread and starts listening through socket.

**ClientSocketService.cs**

```
public ClientSocketService(Socket sock) : this()
    {
        //Assign the Incomign socket to the Socket variable.
        _serviceSocket = sock;

        //Get and assing the network stream for the Socket.
        this._nStream = new NetworkStream(sock);

        //Initialize the Reciever Thread.
        RecieverThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        RecieverThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(RecieverThread_StartListening);
        RecieverThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

I create Objects of this class in another class called server, after the class object is created then, another method adds the class to Collection and  raises the ClientAdded Event Handler.

```
private void AcceptClientSocket(Socket sock)
    {            
        //Initialize new ClientSocketService.            
        ClientSocketService csservice = new ClientSocketService(sock);

        //Add the client to the List
        this.AddClientToList(csservice);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the Client to the List.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="csservice"></param>
    private void AddClientToList(ClientSocketService csservice)
    {
        //Check for any abnormal Disconnections
        this.CheckAbnormalDC(csservice);
        //Ad the ClientSocketService to the List.
        this._clientsocketservices.Add(csservice);
        //Raise the Client Added Event Handler.
        this.OnClientAdded(new ClientSocketServiceEventArgs(csservice));
    }
```

The problem i am facing now is that the Background worker in the ClientSocketService class starts after all the Added event handler events are called.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Put a breakpoint at this.CheckAbnormalDC(csservice);  See if your problem is just a timing issue.  If it is - you need to make sure the background worker is running prior to moving forward with the event handling.

Comment: "The problem i am facing now is that the Background worker in the ClientSocketService class starts after all the Added event handler events are called."  How is that a problem?  Normally you want all the handlers added before something starts.  If the background worker starts before handlers are added then wouldn't it be possible to fire off events that no one receives?

Comment: @Geek I checked it, and its not the timing Issue.

Comment: @Idle_Mind : The reason i need it to work in this way is because, I have few properties in the ClientSocketService class which store information related to the client which is connected, and I need to store these things first so that newly added clientSocketSerive object can be passed in as a parameter to the AddedEventHandler

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have several threads running and you need some sort of syncronisation between this threads. For example:

- MainThread
- Thread1
- Thread2

In this case, even though you start `Thread1` before `Thread2`, there is no guarantee that the threads will execute work in order. It may work once, it may not work the other time.

There are several options available to sync the threads, have a look through

- [Thread Synchronization on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)
- [PART 2: BASIC SYNCHRONIZATION by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)
- Perhaps, [task chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx) will be of interest

Comment: I tried lock and Monitor methods to block the threads. but it didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by adding a new **ClientConnected** event handler in the clientsocketservice class and subscribing to it.

Now I add the ClientSocketService object to the List when the ClientConnectedEventHandler is called. In this way I can do some other Initializing / Authorization work before adding the client to the list.

Thanks all for our help.